# Upon a input change event, scope variable in controller and Interpolated value of same variable on template are different

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I have an app with two routes/templates login and main. The login template's user input values are bound to two scope variables `username` and `isAdmin`. The scope variables are initialized with 'abc' and false, on app startup.

Problem ->

The controller function is always bound to the same initial values which are 
 given on application startup. It does not reflect the scope variables that are 
 being changed on login template

Used {{ }} on markup to see if the binding is happening correctly, the 
 interpolated part actually reflects the value being changed.

Please help if doing it wrong.

```
app.controller('appController', function() {

 $scope.username = "abc"
 $scope.isAdmin = false;

this.radioChange = function() {
 console.log($scope.isAdmin)  // consoles initialized value always
}

this.textChanged = function() {
 console.log($scope.username) // doesn't reflect changed value, shows "abc"
}
})
```

login Template:

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="isAdmin" ng-value="true" ng-
  change="ctrl.radioChange()">
 <input type="radio" ng-model="isAdmin" ng-value="false" ng-
  change="ctrl.radioChange()">

<input type="text" ng-model="username" ng-change="ctrl.textChanged()">

{{isAdmin}}  // view binded correctly to change
{{username}}
```

index.html

```
 <body ng-controller="appController as ctrl">
     <ui-view> </ui-view>  
 </body>
```

app.config

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouteProvider', function($stateProvider, 
$urlRouterProvider) {

  var login = { name: 'login', url: '/', controller='appController', 
                templateUrl: 'login.html'}
  var main  = { name: 'main', url: '/main', controller='appController', 
                templateUrl: 'main.html'}

   $stateProvider.state(login);
   $stateProvider.state(main);
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  }])
```

Comment: Where is `textChange` being called?

Comment: @Chandermani on username input text change. Upon change event, the variable being consoled from controller function is always the initialized value on load. The {{username}} shows the value being changed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be happening because the login template code has a scope (parent) different from `appcontroller` scope (child).

While child scope can read properties from parent, changes to these properties (primitive types specifically) create a new property on child scope.

Get rid of `appController` from the body, instead use the controller association done through route (which you partially have):

```
 var login = { name: 'login', url: '/', controller='appController as ctrl', 
                templateUrl: 'login.html'}

 $stateProvider.state(login);
```

Also it would be better that you avoid scope if using a controller as approach, hence input becomes
`<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.username" ng-change="ctrl.textChanged()">`

Finally this will help you understand issues with scope inheritance https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes